# `onNewInstructionEvent` stops being called during route simulation (HERE Premium SDK)

Tags: navigation

I'm trying to write a turn-by-turn navigation app using the HERE Premium SDK.

I calculate a route and begin simulation of the route. At first, I get the expected turn instructions arriving via the `onNewInstructionEvent` callback. However, after a variable amount of time the callbacks stop arriving. The navigation continues fine on screen, but the turn instructions just stop firing.

I have reproduced this on both the emulator and also on a physical device. On my physical device, the turn instructions often stop arriving after about 10 seconds of simulation. In the emulator, it might last minutes or more, but then the turn instructions stop arriving there too.

I don't see any particularly helpful errors or anything arriving that would indicate any kind of problem, so I'm at a loss as to how to debug this.

I'd appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Are you able to provide an example route, where this issue is reproducible? Also, is it reproducible with the latest HERE SDK Premium v3.18?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport We're no longer using HERE SDK due to lack of support. If we move back to using it and keep running into issues, I'll let you know.